# Removed duplicate object and merge its array element with other Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have developed many complex projects. However, I always get stuck in simple things. Could anyone please guide or share some docs to train on these common logical problems. I have an array of objects and the objects can be duplicate.

Each object has an array property permission: ['add', 'remove']. I want to remove the repeatable object and get its permission array property and merged it with the one we found. Permission array should have unique values.

Please guide also point me to some site or a book which will help me to solve logical problems

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 2,  permission: ['add', 'upload']},
  { id: 2, permission: ['add', 'remove', 'edit'] },
  { id: 3, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 4, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['add', 'read'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['read', 'remove'] },
  { id: 6, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
];
```

```
// Result I am looking for.
[
  { id: 1,  permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 2,  permission: ['add', 'remove', 'edit', 'upload'] },
  { id: 3,  permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 4,  permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 5,  permission: ['add','read', 'remove'] },
  { id: 6,  permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
];
```

```
// Tried so far 

const seen = new Set();

const fa = arr.filter((el) => {
  const duplicate = seen.has(el.id);
  seen.add(el.id);
  return !duplicate;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the usage of external libraries is allowed here, but have you looked into `lodash`? It has a `_merge` feature which I think is doing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work!!!

```js
var arr = [
  { id: 1, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 2,  permission: ['add', 'upload']},
  { id: 2, permission: ['add', 'remove', 'edit'] },
  { id: 3, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 4, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['add', 'read'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['read', 'remove'] },
  { id: 6, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
];

var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    if(res.length == 0) res.push(arr[i]);
    else {
       if ( !res.find(item => item.id == arr[i]['id'])) {
            res.push(arr[i]);
       }
        else  {
            var resIndex = res.findIndex(item => item.id == arr[i]['id']);
            for(var j=0; j<arr[i]['permission'].length; j++) {
                if(res[resIndex]['permission'].indexOf(arr[i]['permission'][j]) === -1) res[resIndex]['permission'].push(arr[i]['permission'][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 2,  permission: ['add', 'upload']},
  { id: 2, permission: ['add', 'remove', 'edit'] },
  { id: 3, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 4, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['add', 'read'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['read', 'remove'] },
  { id: 6, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
];
 

function run(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((previousValue ,currentValue) => {
    let item = previousValue.find(e => e.id === currentValue.id)
    if (item) {
      item.permission =  [...new Set([...item.permission, ...currentValue.permission])]
      return previousValue
    } else {
      return previousValue.concat(currentValue)
    }
  },[])
}
console.log(run(arr))
```

Comment: `upload` permission is missing for `id` `2`

Answer (score 1):

Use array.reduce to create a hash of `id`s and then access the values of it using `Object.values()`,

Please find the code in attached snippet

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 2,  permission: ['add', 'upload']},
  { id: 2, permission: ['add', 'remove', 'edit'] },
  { id: 3, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 4, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['add', 'read'] },
  { id: 5, permission: ['read', 'remove'] },
  { id: 6, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, {id, permission}) => {
    if (!acc[id]) {
      acc[id] = {
        id,
        permission: [...new Set(permission)],
      };
    }
    acc[id] = { 
      id,
      permission: [...new Set([...acc[id].permission, ...permission])],
    };

    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const arr = [
      { id: 1, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
      { id: 2, permission: ['add', 'upload'] },
      { id: 2, permission: ['add', 'remove', 'edit'] },
      { id: 3, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
      { id: 4, permission: ['add', 'remove'] },
      { id: 5, permission: ['add', 'read'] },
      { id: 5, permission: ['read', 'remove'] },
      { id: 6, permission: ['add', 'remove'] }
    ];
    
    let i;
    arr.forEach(function (arrkey, index) {
      for (i = index + 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arrkey.id === arr[i].id) {
          arr[i].permission.forEach(function (per) {
            if (!arrkey.permission.includes(per)) {
              arrkey.permission.push(per);
            }     
          });
          arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    });
    
    console.log(arr);
```

This simple solution should work.

Comment: Related to logical problems, I think maybe you have not worked on javascript projects? It's ok to feel a bit bad about it but with practice, you will be able to overcome these easily. Try some logical problems online ( leetcode, codeforces ) etc